# XML data to ArcGIS

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, xml

I have a question about an XML file that I want to import into ArcGIS.

https://metadata.agiv.be/zoekdienst/apps/tabsearch/?uuid=538c1efa-c754-4cbc-ac2d-d81e6d929807

I have no idea how to do that, and I'm quite new to ArcGIS.

Answer (score 2):

The link you post it brings me to a `Catalogue Service` where the metadata of a cartographic resource is located. This kind of Services are useful to share the information about geographic resources like who's the owner of the data, the extension, where you can download it or buy it, contact point and more other INSPIRE parameters. The XML download option of the site is return a `XML` of the `metadata`, not a GML with the geographic information or something you can convert to SHP, it's just information of the resource. I'm not German so I  don't undertand the page correctly, but it should be a link where you can download or buy that cartographic resource.